# useReducer shows initial state in different component in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to set `loginFlag` in the state throughout the application. I'm using `useReducer` hook to perform that action. It looks like the state is limited to the page `A` where I dispatched the action. When I go to page `B`, I'm seeing the initial state.

Excerpt from my code

Component `A`

```
const Home = () => {
  const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(reducer, initialState);
  console.log("state in home", state);
  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={() => dispatch({ type: "count" })}>Count</button>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Component `B`

```
const About = () => {
  const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(reducer, initialState);
  console.log("state in about", state);
  return (
    <div>
      About page    
    </div>
  );
};
```

I created a working example using [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-usereducer-state-ykovq?file=/src/pages/Home.js:96-331). Could anyone please help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because you are creating two different stateful variables that happen to both be named 'state'.

If you create the state in the App component, and pass it down as a prop to both the Home and About components, it will work.

See [this codesandbox example](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-usereducer-state-forked-ltkkp?file=/src/App.js). It also renders both components as children for the / route (recommended in Router docs) so it console logs the state of both.

Comment: This is great! Also, how do we persist the state? When I refresh my page, the state is being cleared.